# Informix cast Date to integer

Tags: sql, date, casting, integer, informix

Hi is there any way to cast date to integer like 2014/05/29 => 20140509?

Because the database at which I work has just such a value, and I need to make a comparison. I searched the Internet but the only thing I found is conversion to milliseconds since 1970.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used Informix in ages, however I believe this is what you are looking for.  First format the date as a string in the format you want, then cast it to an integer.

```
TO_CHAR(mydatefield,'%Y%m%d')::INTEGER
```